# Randomly select certain indices of two lists to create two new lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indices

Say I have two lists:

```
A = ['cat', 'dog', 'cow', 'pig', 'monkey']
B = ['Felix', 'Fido', 'Moo', 'Trump', 'King Kong']
```

Now I want to create `lists A` and `list B` by selecting 3 random indices (without replacement), while maintaining the relation between the values of `A` and `B`.

For example,

Randomly selected indices: `4, 0, 3`

Therefore,

```
A = ['monkey', 'cat', 'pig']
B = ['King Kong', 'Felix', 'Trump']
```

Is there a method to do this without writing a for-loop which iterates 3 times to select the random indices?

Comment: Yes there is a way to do this but as a new comer to SO you should check the policy for asking questions as it will help you get answers. It would be a lot easier if you ask with some code that you've already tried as this will allow mw to give you a specific answer. Could you include some code?

Comment: Have you looked at python's random library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the lists, then pick 3 random pairs with [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample), and finally split the pairs into separate lists again:

```
import random

pairs = list(zip(A, B))  # make pairs out of the two lists
pairs = random.sample(pairs, 3)  # pick 3 random pairs
A1, B1 = zip(*pairs)  # separate the pairs
```

This is what happens step by step:

```
>>> list(zip(A, B))
[('cat', 'Felix'), ('dog', 'Fido'), ('cow', 'Moo'), ('pig', 'Trump'), ('monkey', 'King Kong')]
>>> random.sample(_, 3)
[('monkey', 'King Kong'), ('pig', 'Trump'), ('dog', 'Fido')]
>>> list(zip(*_))
[('monkey', 'pig', 'dog'), ('King Kong', 'Trump', 'Fido')]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 3):

Python has a sample function that does selection without replacment. You can sample from the indices and apply the sample to your inputs.

```
from random import sample

A = ['cat', 'dog', 'cow', 'pig', 'monkey']
B = ['Felix', 'Fido', 'Moo', 'Trump', 'King Kong']
k = 3

samp = sample(range(len(A)), k)
A_p = [A[i] for i in samp]
B_p = [B[i] for i in samp]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
import numpy as np

indx = np.random.choice(len(A),3,False)

np.array(A)[indx]
Out[593]: array(['cow', 'pig', 'monkey'], dtype='<U6')

np.array(B)[indx]
Out[594]: array(['Moo', 'Trump', 'King Kong'], dtype='<U9')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I like the zip answer best but I would take this approach using *list comprehension*

```
import random   

l1 = ['cat', 'dog', 'cow', 'pig', 'monkey']
l2 = ['Felix', 'Fido', 'Moo', 'Trump', 'King Kong']
r = [random.randint(0, len(l1)-1) for i in range(3)]

A = [l1[i] for i in r]
B = [l2[i] for i in r]
```

> ```
> ~/python/stackoverflow/9.23$ python3.7 loop.py 
> ['monkey', 'cow', 'cat']
> ['King Kong', 'Moo', 'Felix']
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid looping though you can delegate it to a function or dress it up as a list comprehension.
You can loop over each list once, though.

```
#lets assume your randomly selected numbers are 4, 0 and 3
indices = (4,0,3)
# lets assign an ordinal to each index
indices_ordinals = [(ind, ord) for ind, ord in enumerate(indices)]
# now we can re sort the indices, since we have recorded their original sequence
indices_ordinals.sort(key = lambda x: x[0])
# now go through the lists (for simplicity we assume they have equal number of elemwnts) and fill the output dicts
csi = 0 # csi is the index that we are looking for currently
A1 = {}
B1 = {}
for i, elem in enumerate(A):
    if i == indices_ordinals[csi][0]:
        A1[indices_ordinals[1]] : elem
        csi += 1
csi =0
for i, elem in enumerate(B):
    if i == indices_ordinals[csi][0]:
        B1[indices_ordinals[1]] : elem
        csi += 1
#now we only need to sort A1 and B1 to get desired output
A2=[A1[i] for i in sorted(A1)]
B2=[B1[i] for i in sorted(B1)]
```